# GroupBy Function Not Applying

Tags: pandas

I am trying to groupby for the following specializations but I am not getting the expected result (or any for that matter). The data stays ungrouped even after this step. Any idea what's wrong in my code?

```
cols_specials = ['ï»¿Enterprise ID','Specialization','Specialization Branches','Specialization Type']
specials = pd.read_csv(agg_specials, engine='python')
specials = specials.merge(roster, left_on='ï»¿Enterprise ID', right_on='Enterprise ID', how='left')
specials = specials[cols_specials]
specials = specials.groupby(['ï»¿Enterprise ID'])['Specialization'].transform(lambda x: '; '.join(str(x)))
specials.to_csv(end_report_specials, index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: is this normal some symbols in the df's columns: ` 'ï»¿Enterprise ID'`, Kr?

Comment: your data is obviously grouped, please chech jon.doe: this row in column specialization has ```english;math``` what is a result of your transform function in groupby

Comment: That's the desired result that I posted, NOT what is actually happening... As I mentioned, the actual result just yields the same table as if that line of code didn't exist

Answer (score 0):

Please try using agg:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ['john', 'eng', 'build'],
        ['john', 'math', 'build'],
        ['kevin', 'math', 'asp'],
        ['nick', 'sci', 'spi']
    ],
    columns = ['id', 'spec', 'type']
)

df.groupby(['id'])[['spec']].agg(lambda x: ';'.join(x))
```

resiults in:

[image]

if you need to preserve starting number of lines, use transform. transform returns one column:

```py
df['spec_grouped'] = df.groupby(['id'])[['spec']].transform(lambda x: ';'.join(x))
df
```

results in:

[image]